# How to condition the rendering of React function with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to condition the rendering of different React function components, according to specific parameters.

For example, I want to render ComponentA if an input field includes only a number, or ComponentB otherwise. I use a switch case that returns the component that corresponds with the right case. *Important to mention that each of the components includes different hooks (different numbers of states e.g).*

When I run the program, I get an error that a different number of hooks is rendered.
**What is the right way to accomplish this?** Currently I'm using a class that extends the React `Component` class since it does not use Hooks, but I'm trying to find a solution that allows me to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the same number of hooks *within each component*.  If you return a component (rather than directly calling the component function), each component can use a different number of hooks.  For example:

```js
function Component(props) {
  const [field, setField] = useState('');
  const isNumber = !isNaN(parseInt(field)); // or however you want to detect numbers
  //...
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={field} onChange={(e) => setField(e.target.value)}/>
      {isNumber && <Component1/>}
      {!isNumber && <Component2/>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can even do ```{isNumber ? <Component1/> : <Component2/>```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
const MainComp = () => {


const customRender = () =>{
    if(val==1){
        return(<Comp1>)
    }else{
    return (<Comp2>)
    }
}

return(
    <div>
        {customRender}
    </div>
)
}
```